# Compound distribution regression vs random effect model

Tags: regression, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, random-effects-model

What is the difference between a regression model with a compound error distribution (e.g. negative binomial, beta binomial) and a binomial/poison GLM with a random intercept (say Gaussian)? Is it simply the way they model over dispersion and would it be correct to say that, for example, a binomial GLM with a Gaussian random intercept is like a "binomial with a logit transformed Gaussian prior")?